# How to get firefox language setting?

Tags: javascript, firefox

for example
in ie 
we can use "navigator.systemLanguage" to get language setting
but how to get language setting in firefox way?

thx your response.

Cloud

Comment: I assume this is wrong question, you are probably looking for Accept-Language header from HTML specification: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 2):

The following JavaScript will get you all the properties of the navigator object that you can look at:

```
document.write('<pre>');
for (var i in navigator)
{
    document.writeln('navigator.' + i + ' = ' + navigator[i]);
}
document.write('</pre>');
```

My Firefox has this attribute:

```
navigator.language = en-US
```

... which should suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I'm being dense, but I just went into firefox's Options->Content and removed all languages except German/Germany, and navigator.language hasn't changed - it's still en-GB (I'm in the UK).

I'm told if I get the German INSTALL of firefox it will work, but I shouldn't need to do that, right?

The useragent string still contains en-UK, too; but the accept-language on HTTP headers IS set correctly. Anyone know how to get to the correct setting?

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.language
```

Comment: navigator.language is the language that Firefox was installed with, NOT the language the the user is currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Wow BipdelShark was fast! Here is a solution that I use to deal with most browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var language = navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language;
  alert(language);
</script>
```

Comment: No, you're not being dense.  I have a en-US install of Firefox. From Tools.Options.Content.Languages, I deleted English/United States[en-US], and added Spanish[es].  I browse to a website and I can see Firefox sends the HTTP header
Accept-Language: es
The response returns
Content-Language: es-ES
If I use firebug to inspect window.navigator.language, it is "en-US" and my dojo application uses the incorrect language.

Ironically, ie gets this right.