# How to get firefox language setting? (REALLY)

Tags: firefox, locale

I know this question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025281/how-to-get-firefox-language-setting), but the answer given is not the complete story:

I went into Firefox's Options->Content and removed all languages except German/Germany, and navigator.language hasn't changed - it's still en-GB (I'm in the UK).

I'm told if I get the German Firefox INSTALL it will work, but I shouldn't need to do that, right?

The useragent string still contains en-GB, too; but the accept-language on HTTP headers IS set correctly. So this seems to be a bug in Firefox, I spent a bit of time wading through their bugzilla, but I can't see this exact bug logged, though to me it seems a pretty huge oversight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend to use a Firefox Add-on for this task. [Simple Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-locale-switcher/), [Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/locale-switcher/) or [Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/) etc. (* Caution some of this Add-ons may contain ad ware or may not work if you've just updated firefox).

*Another solution is to download a different old firefox version using the language/locale. (Caution) You need and install it in a different folder so you won't overwrite your existing version. [Download here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) I'm using firefox 28 in Spanish. I disabled updates and I rejected using it as my default browser. Only one firefox version should be running at the same time if you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - that probably would work around the bug in that version of Firefox, but when I went back to test this it seems like they've fixed it, now (version 12.0)! Removing the add-on and changing language DOES now work as expected. I'll accept your answer because it would have been useful if the problem hadn't gone away.

Comment: Beware, the latest version contains adware/bloatware

Answer (score 17):

Both navigator.language and the HTTP User-Agent header use the value of the preference "general.useragent.locale", which is hard-coded in intl.properties to the locale of the Firefox build you downloaded:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/locales/en-US/chrome/global/intl.properties#8

Or for your en-GB build:
http://hg.mozilla.org/l10n-central/en-GB/file/88dd673c01f1/toolkit/chrome/global/intl.properties#l8

If you'd like to change it for your build, just load about:config, find general.useragent.locale, double-click it, and change the value.

Comment: @Ted: `navigator.language` may use `general.useragent.locale` (I haven't tested it), but `Accept-Language` doesn't seem to use the `general.useragent.locale` value here. It appears to use `intl.accept_languages`. I manually changed `intl.accept_languages` (i.e. - not through Tools > Options... > Content > Languages) and Live HTTP headers shows Firefox using the new value.

Comment: @Ted: `phpinfo()` also reports the new value of `intl.accept_languages` in the `Accept-Language` HTTP header so it isn't some odd local phenomenon.

Comment: Oh oops, I meant "the User-Agent" header there, but I think I got confused by seeing your prior answer. Sorry!

Comment: Was I correct in asserting that this was a bug and is now fixed?

Comment: This answer is a life changer!:) I wonder why mozilla has to hide so deeply such trivial (and often needed) setting.

Comment: I don't have a general.useragent.locale key in my about:config , should I add it?

Comment: As @GrantWagner stated, it's `intl.accept_languages` instead. @the21st

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that navigator.language returns it's interface language (I assume is GB English), not one that it wants documents in. User-agent string too report which version of firefox was downloaded.

Accept-language is what destination server should check.

I consider this behavior of his quite correct (assuming that it's interface (menus and such) are really in GB english).

Comment: I don't understand why it's good to change one (the accept_language in headers) and not anything else related to locale?

Comment: @Ian: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is that the UI language and language you want to view your websites in may be different. Example: If I am at an Internet cafe in Germany, the German version of Firefox will most likely be installed. I probably can't install another browser, but I want my websites rendered in English. I change the Accept-Language and now I can view websites in the language of my choice even though the UI is in another language.

Comment: @Grant: Exactly. That's exactly the problem we have. The user can only change 'accept-language' if they're on a Firefox that's not localized to the language they want to use. And you can't get to that in javascript from Firefox (you can from IE).

Answer (score 2):

in firefore, about:config, modify the value of "intl.accept_languages", to your required locale, let's say de-DE will do.

Comment: Sorry but my question is once an end user has modified this setting in the UI - how should my JavaScript get to it? - simple answer: it can't.

Comment: i think JS should be able to get this info from user request. accept_language is one of standard request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Accept-Language` value, you can't retrieve if using client-side JavaScript. You'll have to get it from your server.

If you really want this value in client-side JavaScript, then read it on the server and write it back to the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// setting the accept language HTTP header value
// in client-side JavaScript from PHP
var acceptLanguage = '<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: I know. This is our current workaround (using ASP.NET):
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLangauges.
This may sound a bit 'religious', but I don't think we should have to do that, though!